# Is it possible to determine through which object an object was accessed?

Tags: vb.net

Lets say I have these classes

```
Public Class Connection
    Private a as Node
    Private b as Node

    Public Property Self as Node
    Public Property Other as Node

    Public Sub New(a as Node, b as Node) 
        Me.a = a : Me.b = b
        a.Connection = Me : b.Connection = Me
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Node 
    Public Connection as Connection
End Class
```

And I set it up like this

```
Dim a = New Node()
Dim b = New Node()
Dim c = New Connection(a, b);
```

So both nodes share the same Connection object. Now I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to define a getter for Connection properties Self and Other that could detect which object they are being accessed through and alter their return value accordingly?

For example some pseudo code

```
Public Property Other as Node
Get
    If (<CalledThroughObject> = a) Then Return b
    Return a
End Get
```

and this should be the outcome

```
a.Connection.Other = b
b.Connection.Other = a
```

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your question is: No, you can't.

However, you can model your classes differently to achieve what you are trying to do. Here is an example:

```
Public Class Connection
    Private my_node As Node
    Private other_node As Node

    Public ReadOnly Property Self As Node
        Get
            Return my_node
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Other As Node
        Get
            Return other_node
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(myNode As Node, otherNode As Node)
        Me.my_node = myNode
        Me.other_node = otherNode
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now the `Connection` class has a concept of "My Node" and a concept of "Other Node". This means that each node will have a separate instance of the `Connection` class.

Here is how the `Node` class would look like:

```
Public Class Node
    Public Connection As Connection

    Public Sub ConnectWith(otherNode As Node)
        Me.Connection = New Connection(Me, OtherNode)
        OtherNode.Connection = New Connection(OtherNode, Me)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Notice the `ConnectWith` method that allows you to connect one node with another one. Notice how it creates two `Connection` objects for the two nodes. Each connection object knows which is the "Self" node and which is the "Other" node.

Here is how you would use these classes:

```
Dim a = New Node()
Dim b = New Node()

a.ConnectWith(b)
```

Now `a.Connection.Other` would point to `b` and `b.Connection.Other` would point to `a`.